# Build a chain of numbers from 2d array in VBA Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, sequence

There is a table with numbers. See
[Attachment](https://ibb.co/c654mPV)

The first column acts as an index. It has number 0.
It determines which row to jump to.
A number is selected in the row.
By this number, go to the row with this number.
We select a number from a new row and so on.

Limitations.
Numbers are not repeated during transition
The return to the initial number can only be on the transition number equal to the number of rows in the table.

It is necessary to build the longest possible chain of transitions by numbers in the table. Ideally, loop, that is, when the initial number is equal to the final number, and the number of transitions is equal to the number of rows.

For example, let's start with the number 1.
The 1st row contains the only number - 74. Go to 74th row.
In the 74th row select the number that is in the first column (column zero is the row numbering index). There is nothing in the first column in 74th row, so we look further in the following columns. In the 2nd column there is a number 46. Go to the 46th row.
There is a number 19 in the first column of the 46th row. Go to 19th row.
Etc.

If it is impossible to select such a number so that there is no repetition, then output the sequence that turned out to be a file.
Then look for other ways to achieve the longest chain of transitions.

It would be nice if the code could go back one, two, ... n steps back and choose a different path. For example, on the first pass, the code choses the first number from the row and hit a dead end, then it comes back and selects the second or third and repeats again.
I have little understanding of how to do this in code.

At the best, I would like the code to suggest how to fix the input table to get a complete sequence. That is, the code would suggest in which cell the number should be changed to loop the sequence.

I went through this table manually and found at least two sequences that loop at step 86 (now there are 86 rows in the table), but the attached code gives a maximum of 73 steps.

I wrote VBA code in Excel. You can see it below.

Full [xls](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19gZldQa27_tCoiMxG6N59EklkygRdgeD/view?usp=sharing) on Drive.Google.

Tell me, please, how I can solve this problem.
If such problem can not solve using VBA give me an advise, please, which programming language I should use.

```
Function IsUnique(ByRef intArr() As Integer, intNum As Integer) As Boolean

    Dim intPart() As Integer
    
    ReDim intPart(1 To UBound(intArr)) As Integer
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(intArr)
        intPart(i) = intArr(i)
    Next
    
    QuickSortInteger intPart
    
    If (BinarySearchInteger(intPart, intNum) = -1) And (intNum <> 0) Then
        IsUnique = True
    Else
        IsUnique = False
    End If
    
End Function
Sub Main()
    Dim varIData() As Variant
    Dim intTemp(1 To 7) As Integer
    
    Dim intTempWOZeros() As Integer
    
    Dim intTempDSC(1 To 7) As Integer
    Dim intTempCount As Integer
    
    Dim intStore() As Integer
    Dim intIData(1 To 86, 1 To 7) As Integer

    Dim intBegin As Integer
    Dim intCurr As Integer
    Dim str As String
      
    Sheets("For_Macros").Select
        
' Reads the given Excel table in a two-dimensional array
        
    varIData = Range("B1:H86").Value

' In the cycle, the data from the Variant-array tranfer to Integer-array, empty values is replaced by zeros
    
    For i = 1 To 86
        For j = 1 To 7
            If varIData(i, j) = "" Then
                intIData(i, j) = 0
            Else
                intIData(i, j) = CInt(varIData(i, j))
            End If
        Next
    Next
    
    
'   Searching for other paths of the solution
'   Reverse input array. The fisrt element became the last and the last - the first.

'    For i = 1 To 86
'        For j = 1 To 7
'            intTemp(8 - j) = intIData(i, j)
'        Next
'
'        For j = 1 To 7
'            intIData(i, j) = intTemp(j)
'        Next
'    Next

'   Sort rows entire values - ascending
'   I tried to change an order in numbers in each row

'    For i = 1 To 86
'        For j = 1 To 7
'            intTemp(j) = intIData(i, j)
'        Next
'
'        QuickSortInteger intTemp()
'
'        For j = 1 To 7
'            intIData(i, j) = intTemp(j)
'        Next
'    Next
        
  
'   Sort rows entire values - descending
'   I tried to change an order in numbers in each row

'    For i = 1 To 86
'        For j = 1 To 7
'            intTemp(j) = intIData(i, j)
'        Next
'
'        QuickSortInteger intTemp()
'
'        For j = 1 To 7
'            intTempDSC(8 - j) = intTemp(j)
'        Next
'
'        For j = 1 To 7
'            intIData(i, j) = intTempDSC(j)
'        Next
'    Next
    
' The 1st For
For Z = 1 To 86 ' Top level.
                ' 'For ... next' for each start number
                ' At the first iteration we take the number 1 and begin 
                ' form the 1st row, to build a sequence much posible as can
                ' At the 2nd iteratoin we take number two as the first number and begin
                ' form the 1st row, to build a sequence much posible as can

                ' We try go through the array every time starting with new row
                ' and do until we can add in a sequence new unique number
                

    i = Z
    ReDim Preserve intStore(1) ' Array in which we collect all number in a sequence
    intStore(1) = i ' Array initialization with value = i, just like starting with the i-th line,
                    ' and at i-th number we can not returm until amount of collecting number
                    ' will be less than an amount of rows in intIData-array 
                    ' If intIData-array has got 100 row, then we can return
                    ' at the begining row (wherever it be the 1st, the 49th or the 93th) at 100th iteration only
    
    m = 0

' The 2nd For
    For k = 1 To 85
        ReDim Preserve intStore(k + 1)
        intStore(k + 1) = -1
 
        ' We search any non-zero value
        ' We take this number from row selected from intIData
        
        m = 1
        intTempCount = 0
        
        
'       Count amount of zeros
'       Discard zeros
'       Copy one row form 2d-array to 1d-array. 1d-array consists 1 row from intIData data-array

' The 3rd For
        For count = 1 To 7
            intTemp(count) = intIData(i, count)
        Next
' The 3rd For End
'       Count amount of zeros. We arrange the array so that it initially contains non-zero values

        intTempCount = AllZerosAtEnd(intTemp())
              
        ReDim intTempWOZeros(1 To intTempCount)
              
'       Transferring to an array without zeros
' The 4th For
        For count = 1 To intTempCount
            intTempWOZeros(count) = intTemp(count)
        Next
' The 4th For End
        
        intCurr = intTempWOZeros(1)
        m = 1
        
Povtor:
        If IsUnique(intStore, intCurr) Then ' We check the uniqueness of the selected number if unique put it in the output array intStore
            intStore(k + 1) = intCurr
            i = intCurr                     ' and assign the variable i the value of this unique number, the next iteration of the loop will already analyze the string with this number
        Else
            If m <= intTempCount Then ' if there are still numbers in the intTempWOZeros row-array, then view other columns
' The 5th For
                For j = m To intTempCount ' select the next value from the array, increase m by 1 and exit the loop back to check the uniqueness
                    intCurr = intTempWOZeros(j)
                    m = j + 1
                    GoTo Povtor
                Next ' The 5th For End
            Else
                GoTo Metka
            End If
        End If
        

    Next
' The 2nd For End

Metka: ' To fill Excel sheet Search results, sheet created manually
    Sheets("PathOrder").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.Cells(3, Z).Select ' Applied from the 3rd line,
                                  ' in the first line is for an amount of found numbers
                                  ' the 2nd line is the blank
    
' The 6th For
    
    For x = 1 To UBound(intStore)
        If intStore(x) = -1 Then Exit For
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = intStore(x)
        ActiveCell.Cells(2, 1).Select
    Next
    
' The 6th For End

    ' Debug in Debug.Print to see what step the code is in
    ' In case of a loop or in case of too long execution, you can interrupt the execution
    
'    Debug.Print "Z: " & Z & vbCrLf
'    Debug.Print x - 1 & " numbers" & vbCrLf
'
    
Next
' The 1st For End
  
    
End Sub

Function AllZerosAtEnd(intArray() As Integer) As Integer
    Dim intNumZeros As Integer
    Dim intTempArray(1 To 7) As Integer
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim i As Byte
    Dim position As Byte
    Dim intTemp As Integer
    
    
    intNumZeros = 0
    
    For i = 1 To 7
        If intArray(i) = 0 Then intNumZeros = intNumZeros + 1
    Next


    position = 1
    
    If intNumZeros <> 0 Then
        For i = 1 To 7
            If intArray(i) <> 0 Then
                intTempArray(position) = intArray(i)
                position = position + 1
            End If
        Next
    For i = 1 To 7
        intArray(i) = intTempArray(i)
    Next
        
    End If

    AllZerosAtEnd = 7 - intNumZeros
    
End Function
```

Comment: The code i am writing covers all the possible combination while cutting out any path that result in a loop. At cicle one you will have more than 2000 combinations with no loop. At cycle 2 you'll have more than 12000 combinations with just 1 loop. I'm running the cycle 3 right now and i'll have way more than 30000 combinations, while i don't think i'll have many loops detected. Even integrating VBA with in-sheet formulas, i doubt it's possible to have a complete list in a "short" time and with just few files. Are you still interested?

Comment: My current result is a chain of 81 transitions, it really takes a lot of time. *1 -> 74 -> 46 -> 19 -> 29 -> 43 -> 25 -> 26 -> 57 -> 34 -> 75 -> 35 -> 49 -> 3 -> 65 -> 44 -> 8 -> 54 -> 77 -> 84 -> 76 -> 10 -> 18 -> 36 -> 40 -> 23 -> 80 -> 17 -> 6 -> 42 -> 81 -> 78 -> 66 -> 56 -> 63 -> 4 -> 83 -> 24 -> 37 -> 11 -> 47 -> 62 -> 2 -> 64 -> 79 -> 30 -> 55 -> 12 -> 31 -> 85 -> 41 -> 59 -> 70 -> 9 -> 67 -> 13 -> 33 -> 86 -> 51 -> 45 -> 28 -> 32 -> 21 -> 72 -> 52 -> 22 -> 53 -> 14 -> 82 -> 38 -> 69 -> 60 -> 71 -> 50 -> 16 -> 20 -> 61 -> 48 -> 58 -> 15 -> 5 -> 84*

Comment: Cycle 3: 66968 combinations with 3606 of those are loops.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've never thought that this task is so complicated. Yes, I'm still interested but if it will be inconvenient go further stop it, please. It's my own interest in programming at all. I аm trying to solve during whole week but couldn't. What if the program analyzes the input data before starting the search? For example, there is only one way to get to line 42, through the number 6; and one way to get to number 74, through number 1. If we arrive at lines 42 and 74 by some other way, then after 6 and 1, respectively, we will never get there, and 6 and 1 will be overboard.

Comment: 86 transitions which I found manually (It took an additional week):16 -> 75 -> 24 -> 37 -> 11 -> 31 -> 8 -> 40 -> 23 -> 46 -> 55 -> 54 -> 77 -> 85 -> 76 -> 41 -> 47 -> 50 -> 1 -> 74 -> 27 -> 28 -> 32 -> 21 -> 36 -> 3 -> 86 -> 81 -> 69 -> 70 -> 61 -> 71 -> 80 -> 58 -> 15 -> 5 -> 84 -> 12 -> 44 -> 20 -> 2 -> 64 -> 59 -> 49 -> 30 -> 73 -> 62 -> 7 -> 56 -> 83 -> 4 -> 39 -> 48 -> 33 -> 66 -> 65 -> 17 -> 13 -> 34 -> 60 -> 67 -> 79 -> 19 -> 29 -> 25 -> 45 -> 78 -> 51 -> 63 -> 10 -> 57 -> 52 -> 18 -> 26 -> 22 -> 53 -> 14 -> 82 -> 38 -> 9 -> 35 -> 43 -> 6 -> 42 -> 72 -> 68 -> 16 (like the first number)

Comment: @DmitryGoncharovskiy, I edited my answer. My results came out a bit different from what you presented.

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edited answer

I figured out your intentions. See the following new code.

```
Sub BuidChains()
    Dim vData As Variant
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, rstWs As Worksheet
    Dim a As Variant
    Dim n As Integer, sNum As Integer
    Dim Dic As Object
    Dim v As Variant
    
    Set Ws = Sheets("For_Macros")
    Set rstWs = Sheets("Sheet3") 'Sheets.Add 'set the result sheet
    
    vData = Ws.Range("B1:H86").Value
    rstWs.UsedRange.Clear
    
    For n = 1 To 86
        'find first value not empty
        For j = 1 To 7
            If vData(n, j) <> "" Then
                sNum = vData(n, j)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        a = ChainArray(n, vData, Dic, sNum)
        
        Debug.Print n & " : " & Join(a, ",")
        
        'Record it on the sheet.
        With rstWs
            .Cells(1, n) = UBound(a) + 1
            .Cells(3, n) = n
            .Cells(4, n).Resize(UBound(a)) = Application.Transpose(a)
            .Range("cj1") = "Max"
            .Range("cj2") = "Min"
            .Range("cM1").Resize(2).Value = "Start number"
            .Range("cK1") = WorksheetFunction.Max(.Range("a1").Resize(1, 86))
            .Range("cK2") = WorksheetFunction.Min(.Range("a1").Resize(1, 86))
            .Range("cn1") = WorksheetFunction.HLookup(.Range("ck1"), .Range("a1").Resize(3, 86), 3, 0)
            .Range("cn2") = WorksheetFunction.HLookup(.Range("ck2"), .Range("a1").Resize(3, 86), 3, 0)
        End With
    Next n
End Sub
Static Function ChainArray(k As Integer, v As Variant, Dic As Object, sNum As Integer) As Variant
    Dim vR() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim n As Integer, cnt As Integer
    
    If n > 100 Then Exit Function
    If n = 0 Then Dic.Add k, k
    cnt = cnt + 1
    If cnt > 100 Then
        cnt = 0
        n = 0
        Exit Function
    End If
    For j = 1 To 7
            If v(k, j) <> "" Then
                If Not Dic.Exists(v(k, j)) Then
                     n = n + 1
                    ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
                    vR(n) = v(k, j)
                    i = v(k, j)
                    Dic.Add i, i
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
    Next j
    
    DoEvents
    
    ChainArray i, v, Dic, sNum
    ChainArray = vR

End Function
```

### Result Image

[image]

### Result Debugging

My results came out a bit different from what you presented.

```
1 : 74,46,19,29,43,25,26,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,36,40,23,80,17,6,42,81,78,66,56,63,4,83,24,37,11,47,62,2,64,79,41,86,12,31,85,72,68,16,20,61,58,15,5
2 : 64,79,41,47,62,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,16,20,61,58,68,23,80,17,6,42,81,78,66,56,63,4,83,24,37,11,15,5
3 : 65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,23,80,17,6,42,81,78,66,56,63,4,83,24,37,11,47,62,2,64,79,41,86,40,5
4 : 83,24,37,11,47,62,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,16,20,2,64,79,41,86,78,66,56,63
5 : 84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,85,72,68,23,80,17,6,42,81,78,66,56,63,4,83,24,37,11,47,62,2,64,79,41,86,40,29,43,74,46,19,27,28,32,7
6 : 42,81,78,66,56,63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,86,40,23,80,17,68,16,20,2,64,79,41,47,62,7
7 : 63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,86,78,66,56,74,46,19,29,43,25,26,69,27,28,32,51,53,14,83,4,47,62,2,64,79,41,59,70,61,58,68,23,80,17,6,42,81,73,38,9,67,13,40,5,37,11,15,71,33,20,16,50,1
8 : 54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,12,31,85,72,68,23,80,17,6,42,81,78,66,56,63,4,83,24,37,11,47,62,2,64,79,41,86,40,5
9 : 74,46,19,29,43,25,26,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,36,40,23,80,17,6,42,81,78,66,56,63,4,83,24,37,11,47,62,2,64,79,41,86,12,31,85,72,68,16,20,61,58,15,5
10 : 18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,26,69,27,74,46,19,29,43,25,45,38,9,67,64,79,41,47,62,2
11 : 83,4,47,62,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,16,20,2,64,79,41,86,78,66,56,63
12 : 31,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,85,72,68,23,80,17,6,42,81,78,66,56,63,4,83,24,37,11,47,62,2,64,79,41,86,40,5
13 : 40,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,26,69,27,74,46,19,29,43,25,45,38,9,67,64,79,41,47,62,2
14 : 83,4,47,62,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,16,20,2,64,79,41,86,78,66,56,63,11,15,37,48,33,73,38,9,74,46,19,29,43,25,26,69,27,28,32,7
15 : 37,11,83,4,47,62,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,16,20,2,64,79,41,86,78,66,56,63
16 : 20,2,64,79,41,47,62,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,60,36,43,74,46,19,29,7,63,66,56,42,81,78,80,17,6
17 : 80,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,86,78,66,56,63,4,83,24,37,11,47,62,2,64,79,41,59,74,46,19,29,43,25,26,69,27,28,32,7
18 : 57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,25,26,69,27,74,46,19,29,43,6,42,81,78,66,56,63,4,83,24,37,11,47,62,2,64,79,41,86,40,23,80,17,68,16,20,61,58,15,5
19 : 46,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,25,26,69,27,74,58,68,23,80,17,6,42,81,78,66,56,63,4,83,24,37,11,47,62,2,64,79,41,86,40,5
20 : 2,64,79,41,47,62,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,16,50,1,74,46,19,29,43,25,26,69,27,28,32,7,63,66,56,42,81,78,80,17,6
21 : 32,7,63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,86,78,66,56,74,46,19,29,43,25,26,69,27,28,72,68,23,80,17,6,42,81,79,41,47,62,2,64,59,70,61,58,15,37,11,83,4,14,82,38,9,67,13,40,5
22 : 18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,25,26,69,27,74,46,19,29,43,6,42,81,78,66,56,63,4,83,24,37,11,47,62,2,64,79,41,86,40,23,80,17,68,16,20,61,58,15,5
23 : 80,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,86,78,66,56,63,4,83,24,37,11,47,62,2,64,79,41,59,74,46,19,29,43,25,26,69,27,28,32,7
24 : 37,11,83,4,47,62,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,16,20,2,64,79,41,86,78,66,56,63
25 : 26,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,36,43,74,46,19,29,7,63,66,56,42,81,78,80,17,6
26 : 57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,36,43,74,46,19,29,7,63,66,56,42,81,78,80,17,6
27 : 74,46,19,29,43,25,26,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,36,40,23,80,17,6,42,81,78,66,56,63,4,83,24,37,11,47,62,2,64,79,41,86,12,31,85,72,68,16,20,61,58,15,5
28 : 32,7,63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,86,78,66,56,74,46,19,29,43,25,26,69,27,70,61,58,68,23,80,17,6,42,81,79,41,47,62,2,64,59,71,33,73,38,9,67,13,40,5,37,11,83,4,15
29 : 43,74,46,19,27,28,32,7,63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,86,78,66,56,42,81,79,41,47,62,2,64,59,70,61,58,68,23,80,17,6
30 : 84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,85,72,68,23,80,17,6,42,81,78,66,56,63,4,83,24,37,11,47,62,2,64,79,41,86,40,5
31 : 84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,85,72,68,23,80,17,6,42,81,78,66,56,63,4,83,24,37,11,47,62,2,64,79,41,86,40,5
32 : 7,63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,86,78,66,56,74,46,19,29,43,25,26,69,27,28,21,36,40,23,80,17,6,42,81,79,41,47,62,2,64,59,70,61,58,68,16,20
33 : 86,78,66,56,63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3
34 : 75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,52,22,1,74,46,19,29,43,25,26,69,27,28,32,7,63,66,56,42,81,78,80,17,6
35 : 49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,66,56,63,4,83,24,37,11,47,62,2,64,79,41,86,78,7
36 : 43,74,46,19,29,7,63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,86,78,66,56,42,81,79,41,47,62,2,64,59,70,61,58,68,23,80,17,6
37 : 11,83,4,47,62,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,16,20,2,64,79,41,86,78,66,56,63
38 : 9,74,46,19,29,43,25,26,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,36,40,23,80,17,6,42,81,78,66,56,63,4,83,24,37,11,47,62,2,64,79,41,86,12,31,85,72,68,16,20,61,58,15,5
39 : 15,37,11,83,4,47,62,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,16,20,2,64,79,41,86,78,66,56,63
40 : 10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,26,69,27,74,46,19,29,43,25,45,38,9,67,64,79,41,47,62,2
41 : 79,64,2
42 : 81,78,66,56,63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,86,40,23,80,17,6
43 : 74,46,19,29,7,63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,86,78,66,56,42,81,79,41,47,62,2,64,59,70,61,58,68,23,80,17,6
44 : 8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,58,68,23,80,17,6,42,81,78,66,56,63,4,83,24,37,11,47,62,2,64,79,41,86,40,5
45 : 10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,26,69,27,74,46,19,29,43,25,58,68,23,80,17,6,42,81,78,66,56,63,4,83,24,37,11,47,62,2,64,79,41,86,40,5
46 : 19,29,43,74,69,27,28,32,7,63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,86,78,66,56,42,81,79,41,47,62,2,64,59,70,61,58,68,23,80,17,6
47 : 62,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,16,20,2,64,79,41,86,78,66,56,63,4,83,24,37,11,15,5
48 : 47,62,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,16,20,2,64,79,41,86,78,66,56,63,4,83,24,37,11,15,5
49 : 3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,32,7,63,66,56,74,46,19,29,43,25,26,69,27,28,21,36,40,23,80,17,6,42,81,78,51,53,14,83,4,47,62,2,64,79,41,86,12,31,85,72,68,16,20,61,58,15,37,11,39,48,33,73,38,9,67,13,24
50 : 16,20,2,64,79,41,47,62,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,60,36,43,74,46,19,29,7,63,66,56,42,81,78,80,17,6
51 : 63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,86,78,66,56,74,46,19,29,43,25,26,69,27,28,32,7
52 : 18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,25,26,69,27,74,46,19,29,43,6,42,81,78,66,56,63,4,83,24,37,11,47,62,2,64,79,41,86,40,23,80,17,68,16,20,61,58,15,5
53 : 75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,16,20,2,64,79,41,47,62,7,63,66,56,74,46,19,29,43,25,26,69,27,28,32,51,45,38,9,67,13,40,23,80,17,6,42,81,78,33,86,12,31,85,72,68
54 : 77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,31,85,72,68,23,80,17,6,42,81,78,66,56,63,4,83,24,37,11,47,62,2,64,79,41,86,40,5
55 : 23,80,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,86,78,66,56,63,4,83,24,37,11,47,62,2,64,79,41,59,74,46,19,29,43,25,26,69,27,28,32,7
56 : 63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,86,78,66,73,38,9,74,46,19,29,43,25,26,69,27,28,32,7
57 : 34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,26,69,27,74,46,19,29,43,25,45,38,9,67,64,79,41,47,62,2
58 : 68,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,67,64,79,41,47,62,2
59 : 79,41,47,62,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,16,20,2,64,46,19,29,43,74,69,27,28,32,7,63,66,56,42,81,78,80,17,6
60 : 36,43,74,46,19,29,7,63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,86,78,66,56,42,81,79,41,47,62,2,64,59,70,61,58,68,23,80,17,6
61 : 58,68,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,67,64,79,41,47,62,2
62 : 75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,16,20,2,64,79,41,47,67,13,40,23,80,17,6,42,81,78,66,56,63,4,83,24,37,11,15,5
63 : 65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,86,78,66,56,74,46,19,29,43,25,26,69,27,28,32,7
64 : 79,41,47,62,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,16,20,2
65 : 44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,86,78,66,56,63,4,83,24,37,11,47,62,2,64,79,41,59,74,46,19,29,43,25,26,69,27,28,32,7
66 : 56,63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,86,78,7
67 : 64,79,41,47,62,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,16,20,2
68 : 44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,58,15,37,11,83,4,47,62,2,64,79,41,86,78,66,56,63
69 : 27,74,46,19,29,43,25,26,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,36,40,23,80,17,6,42,81,78,66,56,63,4,83,24,37,11,47,62,2,64,79,41,86,12,31,85,72,68,16,20,61,58,15,5
70 : 61,58,68,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,67,64,79,41,47,62,2
71 : 33,86,78,66,56,63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3
72 : 68,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,58,15,37,11,83,4,47,62,2,64,79,41,86,78,66,56,63
73 : 78,66,56,63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,86,40,23,80,17,6,42,81,79,41,47,62,2,64,46,19,29,43,74,69,27,28,32,7
74 : 46,19,29,43,25,26,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,36,40,23,80,17,6,42,81,78,66,56,63,4,83,24,37,11,47,62,2,64,79,41,86,12,31,85,72,68,16,20,61,58,15,5
75 : 35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,16,20,2,64,79,41,47,62,7,63,66,56,74,46,19,29,43,25,26,69,27,28,32,51,53,14,83,4,15,37,11,31,85,72,68,23,80,17,6,42,81,78,33,86,40,5
76 : 10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,12,31,85,72,68,23,80,17,6,42,81,78,66,56,63,4,83,24,37,11,47,62,2,64,79,41,86,40,5
77 : 84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,20,2,64,79,41,47,62,7,63,66,56,74,46,19,29,43,25,26,69,27,28,32,51,53,14,83,4,15,37,11,31,85,72,68,23,80,17,6,42,81,78,33,86,40,5
78 : 66,56,63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,86,40,23,80,17,6,42,81,79,41,47,62,2,64,46,19,29,43,74,69,27,28,32,7
79 : 41,47,62,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,16,20,2,64,46,19,29,43,74,69,27,28,32,7,63,66,56,42,81,78,80,17,6
80 : 65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,86,78,66,56,63,4,83,24,37,11,47,62,2,64,79,41,59,74,46,19,29,43,25,26,69,27,28,32,7
81 : 78,66,56,63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,86,40,23,80,17,6,42,82,64,79,41,47,62,2
82 : 81,78,66,56,63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,86,40,23,80,17,6,42,64,79,41,47,62,2
83 : 4,47,62,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,16,20,2,64,79,41,86,78,66,56,63,11,15,37,14,81,69,27,74,46,19,29,43,25,26,22,1
84 : 76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,85,72,68,23,80,17,6,42,81,78,66,56,63,4,83,24,37,11,47,62,2,64,79,41,86,40,5
85 : 72,68,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,58,15,37,11,83,4,47,62,2,64,79,41,86,78,66,56,63
86 : 78,66,56,63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3
```

I don't know if you got your intentions right. Try it

```
Sub test()
    Dim vData As Variant
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, rstWs As Worksheet
    Dim a() As Variant
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim Dic As Object
    Dim v As Variant
    
    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set Ws = Sheets("For_Macros")
    Set rstWs = Sheets.Add 'set the result sheet
    
    vData = Ws.Range("B1:H86").Value
    
    For n = 1 To 86
        a = myArray(n, vData, Dic)
        Debug.Print n & " : " & Join(a, ",")
        With rstWs
            .Range("a" & n) = n
            .Range("b" & n).Resize(1, UBound(a)) = a
        End With
    Next n
End Sub
Static Function myArray(k As Integer, v As Variant, Dic As Object) As Variant
    Dim vR() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim n As Integer
    
    If n > 83 Then Exit Function
    For j = 1 To 7
        If v(k, j) <> "" Then
            If Dic.Exists(v(k, j)) Then
                n = 0
                Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                Exit Function
            Else
                Dic.Add v(k, j), v(k, j)
            End If
            
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
            vR(n) = v(k, j)
            i = v(k, j)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
    
    DoEvents
    
    myArray i, v, Dic
    myArray = vR

End Function
```

### Debugging results

```
1 : 74,46,19
2 : 64,79,41
3 : 65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3
4 : 83,4
5 : 84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77
6 : 42,81,78,66,56,63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3
7 : 63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3
8 : 54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8
9 : 74,46,19
10 : 18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10
11 : 83,4
12 : 31,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77
13 : 40,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76
14 : 83,4
15 : 37,11,83,4
16 : 20,2,64,79,41
17 : 80,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3
18 : 57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18
19 : 46,19
20 : 2,64,79,41
21 : 32,7,63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3
22 : 18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10
23 : 80,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3
24 : 37,11,83,4
25 : 26,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18
26 : 57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18
27 : 74,46,19
28 : 32,7,63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3
29 : 43,74,46,19
30 : 84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77
31 : 84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77
32 : 7,63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3
33 : 86,78,66,56,63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3
34 : 75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34
35 : 49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35
36 : 43,74,46,19
37 : 11,83,4
38 : 9,74,46,19
39 : 15,37,11,83,4
40 : 10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76
41 : 79,41
42 : 81,78,66,56,63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3
43 : 74,46,19
44 : 8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44
45 : 10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76
46 : 19,46
47 : 62,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34
48 : 47,62,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34
49 : 3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49
50 : 16,20,2,64,79,41
51 : 63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3
52 : 18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10
53 : 75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34
54 : 77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54
55 : 23,80,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3
56 : 63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3
57 : 34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57
58 : 68,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65
59 : 79,41
60 : 36,43,74,46,19
61 : 58,68,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65
62 : 75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34
63 : 65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3
64 : 79,41
65 : 44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65
66 : 56,63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3
67 : 64,79,41
68 : 44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65
69 : 27,74,46,19
70 : 61,58,68,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65
71 : 33,86,78,66,56,63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3
72 : 68,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65
73 : 78,66,56,63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3
74 : 46,19
75 : 35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75
76 : 10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84,76
77 : 84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77
78 : 66,56,63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3
79 : 41,79
80 : 65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3
81 : 78,66,56,63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3
82 : 81,78,66,56,63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3
83 : 4,83
84 : 76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65,44,8,54,77,84
85 : 72,68,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3,65
86 : 78,66,56,63,65,44,8,54,77,84,76,10,18,57,34,75,35,49,3
```

Comment: Fine solution; even the effort having studied the extensive question desserves respect :-)

Comment: @T.M., Thank you.